# Seeking a Teradata Merge alternative

Tags: sql, teradata

I have an existing process where I am using a Merge statement.  I now need to add additional columns in one of the tables.  I added one of the new fields to Table A's primary index, but that data doesn't exist in Table B, the source of the Merge, so the Merge fails.  If I remove the primary index on Table A, Merge also fails.

```html
-- TABLEA Primary Index - COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6
-- TABLEB No Primary Index

Merge into TableA
Using TableB
on A.COL1 = B.COL1
AND A.COL2 = B.COL2
AND A.COL3 = B.COL3
AND A.COL4 = B.COL4
```

This produces error message:  *"MERGE Failed.  [5758] The search condition must fully specify the Target table primary index and partition column(s) and expression must match INSERT specification primary index and partition column(s)."*

If I remove the primary key from TableA I get this message:  *"MERGE Failed.  [9252] An invalid statement was attempted on a table without a primary index: Merge-Into NoPI tables is not allowed."*

So, If I can't use Merge, as TableB doesn't have some of TableA's Primary Index columns, what are my options?  I'm not sure if there are other Teradata functions.

I tried this, but it didn't find the records in TableB, which are not in TableA:

```html
SELECT B.COL1
    ,B.COL2
    ,B.COL11
    ,B.COL8
   ,B.COL9
   ,B.COL3
   ,B.COL4
   ,'N'
FROM TABLEB B   
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
     FROM TABLEA A
     INNER JOIN TABLEB B
      ON B.COL1 = A.COL1
       AND B.COL2 = A.COL2
       AND B.COL3 = A.COL3
       AND B.COL4 = A.COL4)
```

Comment: The Primary Index need not be the same as the Primary Key. You can define a non-unique Primary Index with the original columns and along with a Primary Key constraint that includes the new column, if that's what you want. As far as your other query, you want a correlated subquery not a separate join. In other words instead of `FROM TABLEA A INNER JOIN TABLEB B` you just want `FROM TABLEA A` with the same ON clauses inside the subquery, so that the references to B resolve to the outer query.

Comment: If your previous PI was a good one regarding access & distribution, why did you add another column to it?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no need to add another column to the existing PI, PI <> PK.

Regarding the NOT EXISTS query, it's a non-correlated subquery which results in true if there's any matching row. You need a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT B.COL1
            ,B.COL2
            ,B.COL11
            ,B.COL8
            ,B.COL9
            ,B.COL3
            ,B.COL4
            ,'N'
FROM TABLEB B           
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM TABLEA A
                    WHERE B.COL1 = A.COL1
                        AND B.COL2 = A.COL2
                        AND B.COL3 = A.COL3
                        AND B.COL4 = A.COL4)
```